# How to Count Uniques when using groupby].transform('count') with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe `df`:

```
    Name     Date Symbol   Value
0   Ajay  2018_Q1     AA      10
1   Ajay  2018_Q1     AA      20
2   Faye  2018_Q1     AA      30
3   Faye  2018_Q1     BB      40
4    Ray  2018_Q1     BB      50
5    Ray  2018_Q1     BB      60
6    Ray  2018_Q1     CC      70
7    Ray  2018_Q1     CC      80
8   Clay  2018_Q2     CC      90
9   Clay  2018_Q2     CC      99
```

And I want to add a `Count` column which counts the *unique* number of `Symbols` per `Name` and `Date`. When I do:

```
df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol'])['Name'].nunique()
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol'])['Name'].transform('count')
```

my output looks like:

```
      Name     Date Symbol  Value Count
0     Ajay  2018 Q1     AA     10     3
1     Ajay  2018 Q1     AA     20     3
2     Faye  2018 Q1     AA     30     3
3     Faye  2018 Q1    BBB     40     3
4      Ray  2018 Q1    BBB     50     3
5      Ray  2018 Q1    BBB     60     3
6      Ray  2018 Q1    CCC     70     2
7      Ray  2018 Q1    CCC     80     2
8     Clay  2018 Q2    CCC     90     2
9     Clay  2018 Q2    CCC     99     2
```

But because I want *unique* counts, the desired output is:

```
      Name     Date Symbol  Value Count
0     Ajay  2018 Q1     AA     10     2
1     Ajay  2018 Q1     AA     20     2
2     Faye  2018 Q1     AA     30     2
3     Faye  2018 Q1    BBB     40     2
4      Ray  2018 Q1    BBB     50     2
5      Ray  2018 Q1    BBB     60     2
6      Ray  2018 Q1    CCC     70     1 
7      Ray  2018 Q1    CCC     80     1
8     Clay  2018 Q2    CCC     90     1
9     Clay  2018 Q2    CCC     99     1
```

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `transform` with `nunique`:

```
df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol'])['Name'].transform('nunique')
```

And now:

```
print(df)
```

Is:

```
   Name     Date Symbol  Count
0  Ajay  2018_Q1     AA      2
1  Ajay  2018_Q1     AA      2
2  Faye  2018_Q1     AA      2
3  Faye  2018_Q1     BB      2
4   Ray  2018_Q1     BB      2
5   Ray  2018_Q1     BB      2
6   Ray  2018_Q1     CC      1
7   Ray  2018_Q1     CC      1
8  Clay  2018_Q2     CC      1
9  Clay  2018_Q2     CC      1
```

Comment: Would this still work if I had other columns where the values differed? For example, say I had a column called `Value` and for rows `0` it was `10`, row `1` was `20` and row `3` was `30`?

Comment: Weird... when I do it on my actual dataset, it still doesn't get the uniques. But it does when using the sample dataset in the question. I'll have to do some more testing

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `df['Count'] = df.groupby(['Date', 'Symbol'])['Name'].transform('nunique')`? That should work. Please let me know if that works.